# Date picker is getting blank after changing device language in react native?

Tags: android, react-native, datepicker, android-datepicker

I have app in react native.

if Device language is English date picker is shows correct data..but once i change language to for ex. Chinese i am getting blank date picker.

Please help me to understand the reason behind it.
Any suggestion would be helpful for me.

[image]